# How to package C++ application along with its all dependencies for deployment using docker

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a C++ application which depends on several other third party projects which I clone and build from source. I wanted to now deploy this application as a docker container. Consider following directory structure

```
workspace
├── dependency-project-1
|   ├── lib
|   ├── build
|   ├── include
|   ├── src
|   └── Thirdparty
|      ├── sub-dependency-project-1
|      |  ├── lib
|      |  ├── build
|      |  ├── include
|      |  ├── src
|      |  └── CMakeLists.txt
|      └── sub-dependency-project-N
├── dependency-project-N (with similar structure as dependency-project-1)
└── main-project (with similar structure as dependency-project-1 and depedent on dependency projects above)
```

Those `build` and `lib` folders are created when I built those projects with `cmake` and `make`. I used to run app from `workspace/main-project/build/MyApp`

For deployment, I felt that I will create two stage dockerfile. In one stage I will build all the projects and in second stage I will only copy `build` folder from first stage. The build was successful. But while running the app from the container, it gave following error:

```
./MyApp: error while loading shared libraries: dependency-project-1.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

This `.so` file was in `workspace/dependency-project-1/lib` folder which I did not copy in second stage of dockerfile.

Now I am thinking how can gather all build artefacts (`build`, `lib` and all other build output from all dependency projects and their sub-dependency projects) into one location and then copy them to final image in the second stage of the dockerfile.

I tried to run `make DESTDIR=/workspace/install install` inside `workspace/main-project/build` in the hope that it will gather all the dependencies in the `/workspace/install` folder. But it does not seem to have done that. I could not find `MyApp` in this directory.

What is standard solution to this scenarion?